# Display image chosen from Jfilechooser on Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm trying to make a JPanel that has a button that you click to upload an image. It brings up a dialog box with a JFilechooser that stores the file path name in an ArrayList when you click open. I want the chosen image to appear on the JPanel after it is chosen. I know lots of people have asked this question before, but I've tried all the solutions I can find and I can't get the image to appear. Here's my code for the actionperformed when I click the upload button (AddImages is the Jpanel):

```
private void pic1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        int result = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            String sname = file.getAbsolutePath();
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(sname);
            JLabel label = new JLabel(icon, JLabel.CENTER);
            AddImages.add(label);
        }
    }
```

When I try to upload an image, the image gets stored in the ArrayList (tested this by adding a line that prints the size of the ArrayList after I add the image), but it doesn't show up on the JPanel. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here's the full code for the panel (which is visible). The actionperformed for pic1 and pic2 is the same code, which I've shown above:

addImagePrompt.setText("Add some pics");

```
    pic2.setText("add pic");
    pic2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            pic2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    pic1.setText("add pic");
    pic1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            pic1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout AddImagesLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(AddImages);
    AddImages.setLayout(AddImagesLayout);
    AddImagesLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        AddImagesLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(AddImagesLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(50, 50, 50)
            .addGroup(AddImagesLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(AddImagesLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(pic2)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(pic2name, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 376, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addComponent(pic1)
                .addComponent(addImagePrompt))
            .addContainerGap(161, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    AddImagesLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        AddImagesLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(AddImagesLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(22, 22, 22)
            .addComponent(addImagePrompt)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(pic1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(AddImagesLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(pic2)
                .addComponent(pic2name))
            .addContainerGap(377, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    mainPanel.add(AddImages, "card16");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you are missing here is a proper layout manager.
You can read up on this right here: [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

So adding something like this for example should help you achieve what you desire:

```
AddImages.setLayout(new BoxLayout(AddImages, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
AddImages.add(label);
AddImages.revalidate();
this.pack();
```

Answer (score 1):

After adding a component to a container, you have to call `revalidate()` so that its layout manager (re)computes the positions for child components and repaints them:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(icon, JLabel.CENTER);
AddImages.add(label);
AddImages.revalidate();
```

If you upload multiple images using the same "AddImages" panel you'll see that they are all added the panel as separate components. If that's not what you expect, you'll need to rethink how you approach this.

Comment: Thanks. I tried, but it's still not working though. I also tried with AddImages.revalidate(); AddImages.repaint(); but nothing happens

Comment: We would need to see more of your code - is "AddImages" panel even visible on the screen? Can you make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces your problem?

Comment: I've just updated my original post to include my code

Comment: That code is not **minimal** nor can I run it to **reproduce** the problem. But anyway, your panel seems to use a complicated configuration of `GroupLayout`. Where is the new label you create supposed to be placed in the layout? Is it perhaps being placed outside the area visible in the frame?

Comment: @bld, Yes the problem is the GroupLayout. It expects you to use various constraints to control the location of the component when it is added to the panel. You can't just use the add(...) method with no constraints and expect it to work. Don't use an IDE to generate your code. Then you can be in full control of the layout manager and you will be able to create dynamic GUI's easier. Also, note that variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.